# Global variables are set to null after first class execution in Test NG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am trying to build an automation framework using TestNG where I can be able to run multiple classes inside a suite one after another. I have a base class (TestBase.java) where I have all global (class) variables and BeforeSuite and AfterSuite methods which are initializing and destroying these global variables like WebDriver object that will be used across all test classes.

My testng.xml is like this:

```
<suite name="ShunyaAutomation" >
    <test name="ShunyaAutomation_Firefox" preserve-order="true" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="runType" value="local"/>
        <classes >
            <class name="org.shunya.Test1" />
            <class name="org.shunya.Test2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I want the @BeforeSuite method to initialize the WebDriver object and others, which it does, and then all @Test methods in Test1.java and Test2.java should be able to use the Webdriver object.

When I run this, the @Test methods in Test1.java class successfully run but the moment execution reaches to Test2.java, all these objects including the WebDriver object initialized by the @BeforeSuite method are nullified and I get a NullPointer exception on these objects. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

*I could do it by declaring all variables as static. But I don't want to make all these variables as static as I want to be able to run several suites simultaneously using Selenium Grid and TestNG parallel execution.

Comment: Please post the actual code of these classes.

Comment: why do you want to create driver in suite setup? then how do you run tests in parallel if you want?

Comment: Test1 and Test2 are test classes. Test classes ideally dont pass information between each other. For passing information either use a DataProvider, which woill be a static method in  Base class, or use a factory pattern.

Comment: I suggest you to initialize a driver setup and teardown in `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@BeforeSuite` methods are always run only once for all the suite.

If you have a `TestBase` class between `Test1` and `Test2` which has the `@BeforeSuite` method, TestNG will:

1. Create a `Test1` instance
2. Create a `Test2` instance
3. Call `@BeforeSuite` method from `TestBase` only once, and will take the `Test1` **OR** `Test2` instance for that.

A the end, one instance will have WebDriver object initialized, the other not.

As @Mona suggested it, you should use `@BeforeClass` instead.

Comment: If I use @BeforeClass and initialize the WebDriver object, it'll open new browser for each class. What if I want to run all test methods across different classes using a common WebDriver object i.e. only opening the browser once?

Comment: You have to make a trade off. You can't have only one browser and make parallel tests.